# Over 100% objects are degraded, how this is possible?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, cluster

## Situation

Running a really small ceph cluster:

- with three nodes (each containing mon, osd and mds)
- an admin VM (containing also a mgr-service)
- a pool replicating three times

Just to play around I've removed ane osd and re-added it as a new one using

```
ceph-deploy --overwrite-conf osd --zap-disk <host>:<disk>
```

Now after successful addition the cluster is degraded and recovering, as expected. But there are more objects degraded than I expected (information taken from mgr web interface):

```
Health check update: Degraded data redundancy: 15970/11538 objects degraded (138.412%), 52 pgs degraded (PG_DEGRADED)
```

## Question

How is it possible that more objects are degraded than even exist?

Comment: Hi michi and welcome to Superuser. I'm not sure why your question was downvoted. Perhaps you can add some more details on your setup? Maybe also include what commands you've issued to generate the health check report you've shared.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome. The current ceph version "luminous" logs these messages to the monitor log. It can be inspected with `ceph log last` to get a few lines of detailed state. This output is also part of the ceph-mgr-dashboard visible through web.